# If $a+b$ is an irrational number, is $a-b$ an irrational number, too?

Tags: irrational-numbers

**Question 1:** If $a+b$ is an irrational number. Is $a-b$ an irrational number, too?

**Question 2:** If $\cos(a)-\sin(a)$ is irrational, Is $\sin(a)-\cos(a)$ irrational, too?

Comment: Realted http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157245/the-sum-of-irrationals-is-irrational/

Answer (score 26):

HINT: Try for an example with $a=b$.

For the second question, note that $x-y=-(y-x)$.

Comment: For example if we have $\mathcal{K}=\mathcal{Q}/{0}$ and $a,b$ are some irrationals such that theyc an only be identified as $a=(k)^{1/n}$.

Answer (score 8):

No on 1.  $ (2+\sqrt{5}) + (1 + \sqrt{5}) = 3 + 2\sqrt{5}$, while $ (2+\sqrt{5}) - (1 + \sqrt{5}) = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

Hard problem:

> Is it possible to pick $a$ and $b$ such that $a+b$ is irrational but $a-b$ is rational?

Easy problem:

> Is it possible to pick irrational $c$ and rational $d$ such that you can find $a,b$ such that $a+b = c$ and $a-b = d$?

They're really the same problem, of course....

Comment: Are you *sure* that is a hard problem?  If a == b then...