# Is it possible for a quadratic equation to have one rational root and one irrational root.

Tags: calculus

Is it possible for a quadratic equation  with rational coefficients to have one rational root and one irrational root?

I have seen that there is a post about this, but I dont understand it. 
How can it be shown using quadratic formula?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider $f(x) = (x-p)(x-r)$, where $p \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $r \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$.

---

If all the coefficients of the quadratic polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$ are rationals, i.e. $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$, then either both the roots are rational or both the roots are irrational. This is because of the fact that the roots are given by
$$x^* = \dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
Since $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$, the irrational root can occur only when $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ is irrational (Why?), i.e., $b^2-4ac \neq (p/q)^2$, where $p,q \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q \neq 0$. But if $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ is irrational say $r$, then both the roots $$\dfrac{-b \pm r}{2a}$$ are irrational. You may want to look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157245/the-sum-of-irrationals-is-irrational/157247#157247) to see when the sum of rationals/irrationals is rational/irrational.

Comment: This means that: A quadratic polynomial with rational coefficients cannot have a rational and irrational root? Am I right?

Comment: @Reader Yes. Either both roots are rationals or both roots are irrationals.

Comment: Can you explain your (why?) in the solution above?

Comment: @Reader If $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ were to be rational, then $-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ would be rational and so would be $\dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$.

Comment: Maybe a better way to state the reason: The sum of the roots is $-b/a$, which is rational.  But the sum of a rational plus an irrational must be irrational.  A more elementary reason than the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 10):

Consider $x(x-\pi)=0{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$.

**Edit:** Apparently the OP wants to consider polynomials only with rational coefficients but he failed to mention so in the question.

Since you're asking for exactly two roots, the polynomial must be something like $\lambda(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$. Now you want, [without loss of generality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality), $\lambda =1 \land \alpha\in \Bbb Q \land \beta \in \Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$.

However $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=x^2-(\alpha +\beta)x+\alpha \beta$.

So you wish for $\alpha \beta\in \Bbb Q \land \alpha +\beta\in \Bbb Q$.

But $\alpha \beta\in \Bbb Q \land \alpha +\beta\in \Bbb Q\implies \alpha =0 \land \alpha +\beta\in \Bbb Q \implies \beta \in \Bbb Q$.

Comment: but your polynomial has irrational coefficients.

Comment: "How can it be shown using the quadratic formula?" is the question, but this is nevertheless useful. +1

Comment: @Reader Yes, it does. It that an issue?

Comment: yes.we only allow rational coefficients for our quadratic equation I forgot to write this sorry

Comment: @Reader Edit it into the question, then.

Comment: This argument is much easier and also shows that if there is one rational root and one irrational root, then the coefficient of $x$ and the constant terms both must be irrational (assuming the coefficient of $x^2$ is rational). +1

Answer (score 6):

Suppose $ax^2+bx+c=a(x-p)(x-q)$ with $a,b,c,p$ rational. Then by expanding and comparing coefficients, you see that $q=-p-\dfrac{b}{a}$. So what can you say about $q$?