# Determining the parity of the coefficients of a quadratic given that there is a rational solution

Tags: quadratics, rationality-testing, parity

**Que.**   If the quadratic $ax^2 + bx + c$ has a rational root, and $a$, $b,$ and $c$ are integers, then

A) at least one of $a, b, c$ is even
B) all of $a,b,c$ are even
C) at most one of $a,b,c$ is odd
D) all of $a,b,c$ are odd

So we can say that since the roots are of the form $x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$, for it to be rational, $b^2 - 4ac$ **must** be a perfect square. I am not sure now how to determine the parity of the coefficients given this data.

Comment: Have you tried making random quadratics and checking if they violate one of the criteria? You can rule out $B$ and $C$ this way.

Comment: @TobyMak I was hoping for an approach without using the options to be honest

Comment: Related but not a duplicate: [If the coefficients of a quadratic equation are odd numbers, show that it cannot have rational roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3751165/if-the-coefficients-of-a-quadratic-equation-are-odd-numbers-show-that-it-cannot)

Answer (score 1):

With the quadratic $x^2-6x+5$, you can cross off options $B, C, D$ which leaves only option $A$ by the process of elimination. However, as you stated in the comments, this is not what you wanted.

---

Let $p/q$ and $r/s$ be the two roots of the quadratic. You can form a quadratic equation which satisfies these conditions as follows:

$$\left(x-\frac{p}{q} \right) \left(x - \frac{r}{s} \right) = 0$$
$$\iff \left(qx-p \right) \left(sx-r  \right) = 0$$
$$\iff (qs)x^2-(qr+ps)x+pr = 0$$

If one root is irrational, then $\Delta = \sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ in the quadratic formula must be irrational. Because of the quadratic formula $x = \frac{-b ± \Delta}{2a}$, either both roots are rational or both roots are irrational. This concept is further explained in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/368490/is-it-possible-for-a-quadratic-equation-to-have-one-rational-root-and-one-irrati).

Now that we have confirmed there must be two rational roots, let's check if condition $A$ must always be true. The contrapositive of 'at least one of $a,b,c$ is even is that none of $a,b,c$ are even, which means $qs, qr + ps$ and $pr$ must all be odd. If $qr$ and $ps$ are both even, then at least one of $qs$ and $pr$ is even. However, if $qr$ and $ps$ are both odd, then the resulting sum is also even.

This means that either $qr$ is even and $ps$ is odd, or that $qr$ is odd and $ps$ is even.

Now would be a good time to stop and continue the proof for yourself. If you are interested, the rest of the proof is hidden behind the spoiler effect:

> - Case $1$: $qr$ is even and $ps$ is odd

> Since $qr$ is even, at least one of $q$ and $r$ is even. However, since $\text{even} \times \text{odd} = \text{even}$, either one of $qs$ or $pr$ would be even.

> - Case $2$: $qr$ is odd and $ps$ is even.
>  The same logic applies, so either one of $qs$ or $pr$  would be even.

> This means that the quadratic cannot be written in the form $(qs)x^2-(qr+ps)x+pr = 0$. Reversing the order of the steps means that the quadratic does not have two rational roots. By proving the contrapositive of the statement, we have proved that option $A$ is indeed correct.