# Are the irrationals + zero an additive group?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Is it true that the only way two irrationals can sum to a rational is if they sum to zero?

Thanks!

Comment: What examples have you tried?

Comment: I do not understand the downvotes to this perfectly fine question. Would anyone care to enlighten me?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157245/is-the-sum-and-difference-of-two-irrationals-always-irrational and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867569/are-there-any-non-trivial-counterexamples-to-the-non-closure-of-the-irrational-n

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(Artificial) Counterexample: $\sqrt{2} + (1 - \sqrt{2}) \in \Bbb Q$.

Comment: Of course, every counterexample can be written similarly.

Comment: What got downvoted?

Comment: it should be artificial right?

Comment: @clark Yes, thank you.

Comment: I am sorry.. :/ It certainly wasn't me. I appreciated your answer.

Comment: Why sweat the downvote (which looks like it's been removed anyway)? You got eight (eight!) upvotes, which your answer didn't deserve in my opinion. Take the rough with the smooth!

Answer (score 5):

No. All counterexamples will be of form $\alpha + (q- \alpha)$, $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}$, $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. (Can you prove this?)

Comment: Your comment is really the result I'm looking for.. I was trying to prove that $k = (1/\pi) \pm \sqrt{2m/\pi}$ has no solutions for $k, m$ integers. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Dan use the fact that $\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}}$ is transcendental.

Comment: Note that algebraic numbers _do_ form an additive group.

Comment: @Fernando: Suppose $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}$, $p \in \mathbb{Q}$, and $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha + \beta = p$. Then $\beta = p - \alpha$. That was easy! :)

Comment: @Dan first show that $\sqrt{\frac{2 \cdot m}{\pi}}$ is transcendental and then write your equation as a polynomial in $\sqrt{\frac{2 \cdot m}{\pi}}$.  I don't think you should need much beyond the definition of transcendental.

Comment: $0 = (1/2m)x^2 \pm x - k$ cannot have the transcendental $\sqrt{2m/\pi}$ as a solution. Got it! Thanks so much, Dan!

Comment: I am confused. I had accepted another answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. $p/q + i$ minus $i$ is rational. Where $i$ is irrational.