# Suppose that $x$ and $y$ are irrational, but $x + y$ is rational. Prove that $x -y$ is irrational.

Tags: proof-verification, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

i was wondering if someone could check my proof
$Q= \{a/b , c,d : a,c ∈ \mathbb Z , b,d ∈ N>0\}$
$a/b =x+y$

$a/b -y=x$

proof by contradiction.

Let $x-y$ is rational

$c/d = x-y$

sub $a/b -y = x$ in for $x$

$c/d = (a/b -y) - y$

$a/b - c/d = 2y$

This is a contradiction because $a/b$ and $c/d$ are not in their lowest terms.

there it can be said $x-y$ is irrational

Comment: What does $\frac ab $ and $\frac cd$ not being in their lowest terms (says who, by the way?) have to do with the concluion?

Comment: Definition of a rational number states that the denominator and numerator  must be in their lowest forms

Comment: You were good up until the last step.  Dividing by $2$ you showed that (under the assumption that $\x\pm y\in \mathbb Q$) $y$ is rational.  That's all you need!  Nothing at all to do with "lowest terms".

Comment: @josh The fact that you did not write something in the form that definition demands doesn't mean that it is impossible to do so. It just means that you did not do it (allegedly, because you have no ground to assume that $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)\ne1$ either).

Comment: What i am try to say, is since (a/b) - (c/d) have a common factor they are not in their lowest possible form and thus violate my assumption.i think i am a little lost on how to disprove my final line as to create a contradiction

Comment: @josh: You should say: $\frac{a/b-c/d}2$ is a rational number (you don't need to worry about lowest terms at all), so it is a contradiction for this to equal $y$, because we assumed that $y$ is irrational.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your proof seems  right.

I like the following writing.

If $x-y\in\mathbb Q$ so $x-y+x+y=2x\in\mathbb Q$, which says $x\in\mathbb Q$, which is a contradiction.

Id est, $x-y\not\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Can you further clarify what you mean, i don't quite understand.

Comment: The sum of two rational numbers it's a rational number. If x-y and x+y are rational numbers, so x-y+x+y it's a rational number, which says 2x is a rational number. I hope, now it's clear.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $a,b \in\mathbb Q\implies \dfrac{a\pm b}2\in\mathbb Q$.

Apply this to $a=x+y$, $b=x-y$ to obtain a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Sum of rational and irrational numbers is irrational. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542808/rational-irrational-always-irrational).

If $x,y$ are irrational and $x+y$ is rational, then:
$$x-y=(x+y)-2y \ \text{is irrational.}$$