# subtraction of two irrational numbers to get a rational

Tags: arithmetic, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Say you have a number like $\pi$ or e. Is it possible to subtract another number from it and end up with a rational number? I mean I guess you could write an equation like $\pi-x=3$ But could there ever be a solution for x (that we could know and write out)?

Correction: Any number besides the irrational number itself. Damn math ppl are too quick..

Comment: added a couple, but was really drawing blank on the tags, If you have a suggestion, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: You can always do things like $\sqrt{2} - (\sqrt{2} - 3) = 3$.

Comment: Sure, you definitely know it and you can also write it out. $x=\pi -3$.

Comment: Note: No proof is known to determine whether $x = \pi + e$ is rational or irrational, even if we know very well that each addend is rational.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Each addend is irrational.

Comment: What do you mean with "That we could know and write out"?

Comment: See: [Is the sum and difference of two irrationals always irrational?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157245/is-the-sum-and-difference-of-two-irrationals-always-irrational)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you take any real number $x\in\mathbb{R}$ you can show that the set of $y\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x-y\in\mathbb{Q}$ is exactly $x+\mathbb{Q}$.

> Let $y$ be in $\mathbb{R}$ with $x-y$ being rational then $y=x-(x-y)$ so that $y\in x+\mathbb{Q}$. On the other hand, if $y=x+q$ with $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ then $x-y=-q\in\mathbb{Q}$.

So this is kind of easy. However I think that it is not known wether $\pi+e$ is rational or not... What we know is that either $\pi e$ or $\pi+e$ (maybe both) is irrational...

> Assume that both $\pi e$ and $\pi+e$ are rational then :
>
> $P(x):=(x-\pi)(x-e)=x^2-(\pi+e)x+\pi e$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients. This implies that both $\pi$ and $e$ are algebraic numbers which cannot be true...

Comment: I'm very interested in that theorem you described? Would you be willing to put a quick proof?

Comment: @user3256725, see the highlighted parts...

Comment: Unrelated, but it always blows my mind that seemingly easy facts are so difficult to prove. Sometimes a theory sounds ridiculous and is simple to prove; other times it takes us centuries to prove whether $\pi e$ is transcendental or not..

Comment: Yes, thank you clement, i truly wish i could up vote more than once

Comment: @ElliotG If the answer is correct, we don't even know that $\pi\mathrm{e}$ is irrational, let alone transcendental!

Answer (score 20):

$\pi - \pi = 0$ which is rational.

Edit: $\pi - (\pi -1) = 1$ which is a difference of two different irrationals which is rational.  How's that?

Comment: You sneaky math people....

Comment: Haha.  We are trained to look for the most trivial counter examples and build up more interesting ones from there ;)

Comment: @CPM This makes me feel a lot better, actually -- that there's *training* in how to find (most-)trivial counterexamples. Explains why I don't see them nearly so readily.

Answer (score 6):

.223456789101112131415...  -  .123456789101112131415... = .1