# How do I prove that the sum of a rational and irrational number is irrational?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

How do I prove that the following proposition is true?

> The sum of any rational number and any irrational number is irrational.

I am currently a beginner at discrete math and I am still getting used to the format of writing proofs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the sum and difference of two irrationals always irrational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157245/is-the-sum-and-difference-of-two-irrationals-always-irrational)

Comment: The difference of two rational numbers is always rational. See $\frac{z_1}{z_2}-\frac{z_3}{z_4}=\frac{z_1z_4-z_3z_2}{z_2z_4}$, where all the $z_i$s are integers. If the sum of an irrational and rational were rational, then there exists an irrational that can be expressed as the difference of two rationals- a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Let $r$ be rational and let $i$ be irrational.

Now *assume* that $s:=r+i$ is rational.

Subtractiong $r$ on both sides we find $s-r=i$.

But $s$ and $r$ are both rational and it is well known that in that case $s-r$ is a rational number.

But also $s-r=i$ hence is irrational.

This cannot go together so actually we deduced a contradiction.

Then we are allowed to conclude that our assumption is false which means exactly that $s$ is irrational.

Answer (score 2):

Say we have $r\in\mathbb{R/\mathbb{Q}}$ and $s\in\mathbb{Q}$. Now assume by contradiction that $r+s\in\mathbb{Q}$. Therefore, there exists such $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ that satisfies $r+s=q$.

Now let's transfer s. $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field, so $q,s\in\mathbb{Q}$ implies $r=q-s\in\mathbb{Q}$, and that's a contradiction to the initial assumption that $r\notin\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: I think the somewhat more usual notation for "the set of irrationals" is $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$, produced with "`\setminus`".